# How to use FIN in TCP and why?

Tags: tcp

I recently am attempting to study the TCP, but a post graduate tell me the FIN is also used in  going to create a connection, that 3 handshakes.

Following is my mind to the process of 3 handshakes:

1. Client A post a datagram within SYN to Client B.
2. Client B received it, and immediately posted another datagram within SYN and ACK.
3. Client A received it, and immediately posted another datagram within ACK to Client B.

When the 3rd step is DONE, the connection is going to be built.
Here is the question, I don't find any datagram with FIN in 3 steps.

Comment: There is a complete TCP state diagram in RFC 793, which should have been the first place you looked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIN` is not used in creating a connection. It's used to close a connection.

However, the connection can be closed with FIN halfway through a handshake, as [this diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg) makes clear. Perhaps this is what the Post Grad was referring to?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I maybe need a more comprehension about the TCP state image.